# How to use Spring boot server sent events to update angular dashboard?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, server-sent-events

I want to develop a dashboard with a bar chart. This bar chart`s bars based on the data values which are in the database values.

Suppose a bar chart need to be drawn like x axis - status ,y - number of records. So data will be added using seperate API and after that data added into DB i want to reprent it in the bar chart.

I just want to is this possible with SSE? if yes how can i start?

Thanks.

Comment: If you want server to browser communication, you can use socket to send updated data to browser. Whenever your another api updates the DB, send updated data socket so that browser can update it's chart.

Comment: @Ok, But my concern is can we fetch recently inseted data in real time from DB or sending data inflight?

Comment: You can fetch, but you never know in browser that data has been updated in db. One inefficient approach is pull data regularly from backend on an interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your source data are in some particular database, you can try to use https://r2dbc.io (reactive connector to some relational databases), make use of database triggers together with LISTEN/NOTIFY (available at least in postgresql) to make your path fully reactive (resource effective).

If you can choose "database" technology, have a look at https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/ (see issues. it seems that original founder does not develop anymore, but seems "feature complete"), or perhaps some way to use mongodb and its "live query", or [redis](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-data-reactive-redis/).

Please provide feedback about way you have gone and I can elaborate it more deeply.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two approaches (For single instance application):

**Database pulling**: just pull regularly table for new entries, and then produce an SSE.

**Pub-Sub:** Just Implement an internal app queue (using Publish–subscribe pattern, Use a **Flux** for the Weblfux or any of the **Queue** implementation (**PriorityQueue** for example) for the Spring MVC). Push a message to the queue as soon as it's saved to the database and on the Consumer side (your controller) publish that message.

You can create SSE:

- Spring MVC:  Just use **SseEmitter**  and an **ExecutorService** to produce messages.
- WebFlux: Produce messages using Flux.

```
The pulling approach has the drawback that it adds unnecessary load on your database.
```

Don't forget to setup procution type to `MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE`

---

Some Spring SSE samples [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-server-sent-events)